# View doesn't return HttpResponse

Tags: django, django-views

The view iot.views.post_new didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Hope everybody help please.

This is my views.py file:

```
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            ct = form.save(commit=False)
            ct.author = request.user
            ct.upload_time = request.upload_time
            ct.save()
            return redirect('iot:detail', pk=ct.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'iot/post.html', {"form":form})
```

Comment: Could you ask in English, please, rather than (I'm guessing) Vietnamese?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didn't return an HttpResponse object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505250/didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object)

Comment: Can you guide me how to fix it.

Comment: I would also recommend you to avoid writing blog about things you have to ask about in SO. Especially if you 'want the fix'  rather then knowledge and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `else`

```
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            ct = form.save(commit=False)
            ct.author = request.user
            ct.upload_time = request.upload_time
            ct.save()
            return redirect('iot:detail', pk=ct.pk)

    form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'iot/post.html', {"form":form})
```

Comment: unsuccessful . Data is not saved to the database

Comment: I'm doing my blog post, can you help me?

Comment: The only reason it isn't getting saved is there is an error in the form.  Ensure you're showing your errors on the html page so you can see what isn't working

Answer (score 0):

If the form isn't valid in your `if` clause and you POST a response, it won't return `render`. That's what the error message is complaining about.

Comment: yes. I know . But I want to get the fix. I'm doing a blog post for my blog

Answer (score 0):

```
 The view store.views.updateItem didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.


def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']

    print('Action:', action)
    print('Product:', productId)

    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)

    orderItem.save()

    if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
        orderItem.delete()
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to this answer