# Django form error didn't return an HttpResponse object when entering an error in the sign up form

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

Everything works perfect except if you fill in the form incorrectly. For example 2 different passwords. I appreciate this question [is similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505250/didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object), but I believe it is different. My view does not have this issue.  I have tried everything I have seen in every other post and it does not work. Also I'm pretty sure that this code used to work and for some reason now it doesn't.

This is the error:

```
raise ValueError("The view %s.%s didn't return an HttpResponse object." % (callback.__module__, view_name))
ValueError: The view main.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

This is the view

```
def reg(request):    
    if request.method =='POST':        
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username= request.POST.get('username','')
            email= request.POST.get('email','')
            subject = 'Hi {0} Welcome to blabla'.format(username)
            msg="Hi {0},".format(username)
            msg=msg+settings.WELCOME_EMAIL
            message = msg

            recipients = ['info@blabla.com']
            if email:
                recipients.append(email)            

            send_mail(subject, message, 'info@blabla.com', recipients, fail_silently=False)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thank-you')
    else:
        form = MyRegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'reg.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: That is not the full view. Show the *whole* thing, making sure you have the correct indentation.

Comment: It gets skewed when I enter it and then it looks like the indentaion is incorrect. But Ill try add it again

Comment: @DanielRoseman all there now

Comment: But hang on, the error is talking about `home`, not `reg`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Aha ! . Yes youre right. I feel so stupid. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DanielRoseman Turns out my template was pointing at the wrong view. Feel free to add that as the answer